# CodeSynthesis C++Tree 'time' in namespace '::' does not name a type

Tags: c++, xml, xsd, codesynthesis

I'm trying to use CodeSynthesis C++/Tree to translate a xsd into C++ classes. 
In the xsd I have an element named time looks like this:

```
<xs:element name="time">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="seconds" use="required" type="xs:double"/>
  ... other attributes
</xs:complexType>
```

In the converted C++ header it's defined as:

```
typedef ::time time_type;
```

and when compiling it gives me an error message saying

```
'time' in namespace '::' does not name a type
```

However if I change the element's name to 'times' or anything else, it would compile fine. What could possibly be the reason behind this behavior? 
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because `::time` is the same as [`std::time`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time).

Comment: Isn't this statement a bit too strong? It *can* be the same, and apparently *is* the same *in the OP's implementation,* but it does not have to be universally the case.

Comment: Thanks. I'm suspecting the same thing. But as I'm not terribly familiar with CodeSynthesis, I'm not quite sure how to avoid this situation. obviously I can't changed the xsd as it was given to me to make my code comply with it's specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, now I read a little bit more on the documentation, it says

*"A vocabulary without a namespace is mapped to the global scope. This also can be altered with the above options by using an empty name for the XML namespace:"*

So the solution is to add the following when converting xsd to C++ files

```
--namespace-map =cs
```